# Attributes.add and onmouseover

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, attributes, onmouseover, flyout

I have a databound gridview that use to display pictures I fetch from a server.  Im trying to set it up to create a flyout when I mouse over one of the images that enlarges the images.  I have encountered a problem though when it comes to adding the attribute to the databound row.I currently have the code

```
e.Row.Cells(2).Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "flyoutimg.ImageUrl=""" + imgstr + """;")
```

However, this line of code causes me to have a problem in that the imgstr (which contains the url for the image on the server) does not get passed through into the javascript/aspx of the page.  When I boot up the page I can try to mouse over things but it simpally does not work.

Ive tried to put the flyout.ImageUrl in its own string and pass that into the attribute but that does not work either.  The only research I could find on this was from two years ago stating that the Attributes.Add encoded apostrophes but not quotation marks.

Any suggestions?

```
imgstr = dsMyName.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Photo").ToString
```

Im pulling imgstr from a server and doing a .ToString which I believe is redundant.

Comment: I assume the rest of the JS code is getting passed to the client?  How also are you populating imgstr?

Comment: Yes, the rest of the JS codes being passed through.  Im creating imgstr by pulling a url from a database.  Ill add the code above.

Comment: have you tried something along the lines of creating the string prior?  say string flyoutString = ""flyoutimg.ImageUrl=" + imgstr + ";"; or something along those lines, then injecting flyoutString into the Add()?  also have you checked to see if imgstr actually returns a good string?

Answer (score 1):

Try it with a single quote, as in:

```
e.Row.Cells(2).Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "flyoutimg.ImageUrl='" + imgstr + "';")
```

This is because I think what .NET does is render this:

```
onmouseover="flyoutimg.ImageUrl='XYZ'"
```

If you have double-quotes, it would get messed up thinking it was at the end of the attribute and potentially truncate the value.

Comment: When I do this, I get the error "flyoutimg is undefined" when I go to mouseover the cell.  It produces the code             onmouseover="flyoutimg.ImageUrl=&#39;~/Images/Handsets/Alcatel_308A_-_Black.jpg&#39;;"

Comment: If that is the error, I'm not sure why you weren't getting it before.  If that is an element, you may want to try `document.getElementById('flyoutimg')`

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to have the double quotes?

Try this:

```
e.Row.Cells(2).Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "flyoutimg.ImageUrl='" + imgstr + " ';")
```

Notice I used a single quote which is legit HTML.

or try escaping it:

```
e.Row.Cells(2).Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "flyoutimg.ImageUrl=\"" + imgstr + "\";")
```

Comment: VB uses "" as a double quote escape